# Ghost4J PDFConverter generating 0KB PDF File

Tags: java, pdf, ghost4j

I'm using ghost4j to convert PS file to PDF. I have tested it's reading the ps file correctly by using the `getPageCount()` method it's returning the correct page count. However the output pdf file that's generating is 0KB in size and have not content in it.

Here is my conversion code

```
public static File converPsToPdf(File psFile){
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    File tempFile=null;
    try{
        //load PostScript document
        PSDocument document = new PSDocument();
        document.load(psFile);
        //create OutputStream
        //tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".pdf", null);
        tempFile=new File("C:/Users/DOS20/Desktop/rendition.pdf");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        //create converter
        PDFConverter converter = new PDFConverter();
        //set options
        converter.setPDFSettings(PDFConverter.OPTION_PDFSETTINGS_PREPRESS);
        //convert
        converter.convert(document, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally{
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos);
    }
    return tempFile;
}
```

Comment: Please show your `example.ps` file (preferably a stripped down example)
so that we can reproduce your problem.
What error message did you get?
Instead of `System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());`
you should do `e.printStackTrace();`
do get more detailed error information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve the issue by using `org.ghost4j.Ghostscript`

```
public static File convertPSToPdf(String psFile){
    Ghostscript gs = Ghostscript.getInstance();
    String[] gsArgs = new String[8];
    gsArgs[1] = "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite";
    gsArgs[2] = "-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4";
    gsArgs[3] = "-dNOPAUSE";
    gsArgs[4] = "-dBATCH";
    gsArgs[5] = "-r150";
    gsArgs[6] = "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/DOS20/Desktop/rendition.pdf";
    gsArgs[7] = psFile;
    try {
        gs.initialize(gsArgs);
        gs.exit();
        return new File("C:/Users/DOS20/Desktop/rendition.pdf");
    } catch (GhostscriptException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```